# Delete array pointer?

Tags: c++, memory-management

How do I delete the memory that have been allocated for array `models`, `names`? I tried every method but it always crashes when I run it.

```
int main()
{

    vector<Person*> people;

    const int PERSON_SZ = 4;
    char * names[] = {"Jim", "Fred", "Harry", "Linda"};
    int ages[] = { 23, 35, 52, 59 };

    for (int i = 0; i < PERSON_SZ; i++)
    {

        Person * temp = new Person(names[i], ages[i]);
        people.push_back(temp);
    }

    // A vector of Car pointers
    vector<Car*> cars;

    const int CAR_SZ = 3;
    char * models[] = { "Festiva", "Ferrarri", "Prius" };
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < CAR_SZ; i++)
    {

        Car * temp = new Car(models[i]);
        temp->set_driver(people[rand() % (people.size())]);
        temp->set_owner(people[rand() % (people.size())]);
        cars.push_back(temp);
    }



    for (int p = 0; p < people.size(); p++)
    {
        people[p]->increment_age();
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < cars.size(); c++)
    {
        cars[c]->print();
    }

    delete [] names;
    for ( int r = 0; r < CAR_SZ; ++r )
       {
           delete [] models[r];
       }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoiding pointers can simplify this code a lot and would be *much* less error-prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't allocate `models` and `names` using `new`, so you cannot `delete` them.

Both arrays are allocated on the stack and are automatically deleted, when the function returns.

The contents of the (string) arrays (i.e. the strings itselves) are stored in the global data segment and cannot be freed at all. This would also be dangerous because the compiler might use the same string constant at different places in the program.

Answer (score 2):

The models array and the names array are both statically allocated.  You didn't use `new` to create them, you don't need to delete them.  You should, however, change their types as follows:

```
const char * names[] = {"Jim", "Fred", "Harry", "Linda"};
const char * models[] = { "Festiva", "Ferrarri", "Prius" };
```

because they are pointers to string literals, which are read-only.

Comment: so what should i delete? because there are 14 leaked objects when i run it 
Leaked object at 003E3BA8 (size 8, 00402A43)
Leaked object at 003E3C08 (size 18, 00432389)
Leaked object at 003E3C48 (size 8, 00402A43)
Leaked object at 003E3C78 (size 18, 00432389)
Leaked object at 003E3BD8 (size 8, 00402A43)
Leaked object at 003E3CB8 (size 20, 00432389)
Leaked object at 003E3CF8 (size 12, 00402C3B)
Leaked object at 003E3D60 (size 21, 00432389)
Leaked object at 003E3DA0 (size 12, h28.cpp:182)
Leaked object at 003E3E08 (size 18, 00432389)
Leaked object at 003E3E48 (size 12, 00402C3B)
*** 14 leaks found

Comment: used this code to delete vector pointer... thanks for helping mefor (int c = 0; c < cars.size(); c++)
        delete cars[c];
    for (int p = 0; p < people.size(); p++)
        delete people[p];
    return 0;

Answer (score 2):

The variable `names` and `models` are not dynamically allocated, and neither is the data in those arrays. So no need to free them or their contents.

The two `vector` contains data that need to be free'd on the other hand.

Comment: how do i delete vector point? should i create a loop and delete each item inside the vector?

Comment: @RichardNguyen Yes, that's how you do it.

Answer (score 2):

You did not allocate `names`, and `models`. You don't need to free or `delete` them from memory.

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, this is neither required nor legal...

```
delete [] names;
```

Since you didn't `new` `names`.

Neither is this...

```
for ( int r = 0; r < CAR_SZ; ++r )
{
     delete [] models[r];
}
```

Since you didn't `new` any of the `models`.

But you do still have some memory leaks!

For each `car` instance you `new`ed and stored in the `cars` `vector`, you need to call `delete`. Here is one way:

```
for (std::vector<Car*>::iterator car = cars.begin(), done = cars.end(); car != done; ++car)
{
    delete *car;
}
```

Note that the `*` there dereferences the **`iterator`**, yielding the raw pointer you `new`ed.

The problem with this approach is that it leaves you with a `vector` full of dangling pointers. You could either reset them in the loop or `clear()` the `vector` after the loop has terminated. Perhaps a better approach would be:

```
while (not cars.empty())
{
    delete cars.back();
    cars.pop_back();
}
```

Which `delete`s each `car`, then removes its pointer from the `vector`.

Similarly for each `person` you `new`ed and stored in `people`:

```
while (not people.empty())
{
    delete people.back();
    people.pop_back();
}
```

As a rule of thumb, there should be one `delete` for every `new` and one `delete[]` for every `new ... []`. But you'll do well to learn about [smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).

Answer (score 1):

names and models are not pointing heap-allocated area. Don't delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete. It does not compile. Please enable all warnings and debugging for your compiler, e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g` if using GCC and improve your code till you get no warning

```
char * names[] = {"Jim", "Fred", "Harry", "Linda"};
delete [] names;
```

This is incorrect. You can only `delete` something that you obtained thru `new`.

Comment: well, i didnt included the header for person and car class that's y